Ansible- Loop over sub items
Struggling to loop over sub items.
This is my family set_fact output
   "family": {
        "parent": {
            "child1": {
                "total": "1.0GB",
                "child": "child1",
                "parent": "priyanka"
            },
            {
            other items
            }
        child2: {
                "total": "1.0GB",
                "child": "child2",
                "parent": "priyanka"
            },
        {
         other parent items...      
    

and below one is my time set_fact output

    "time": {
        "parent": {
            "child1": [
                {
                    "time": "2024-04-28 00:15:00",
                    "duration": 7,
                    "name": "abc"
                },
            ],
            "child2": [
                {
                    "time": "2024-04-28 00:15:00",
                    "duration": 7,
                    "name": "asd"
                },
        other items and parent items and so on.

and written below task to group by child and parent(family and time)
       - set_fact:
            updated_transformed: "{{ updated_transformed | default({}) | combine({item.key: {subitem.key: {'time': subitem.value | map(attribute='time') | join(','), 'duration': subitem.value | map(attribute='duration') | join(','), 'name': subitem.value | map(attribute='name') | join(',')} }}, recursive=True) }}"
        loop: "{{ time | dict2items }}"
        loop_control:
          loop_var: item
        vars:
          subitem: "{{ item.value | dict2items | first }}"
      - set_fact:
        family: "{{ family |  combine(updated_transformed, recursive=True) }}"
    
      - name: final snapshot
        debug: var=family

This will group only one child in each parent. However i need to group all childs.

Because each 'parent' can have multiple 'children', you would need to use a nested loop.
Something like so:
main.yml
- include_tasks: children.yml
  loop: "{{ time | dict2items }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: parent

children.yml
- set_fact:
    your_variable: "{{ your_variable | default({}) | combine({parent['key']: {child['key']: {'time': child['value']['time'] }}}, recursive=True) }}"
  loop: "{{ parent['value'] | dict2items }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: child

The nested loop behaviour is documented on docs.ansible.com.
